# Problem with [R=301]

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

Some of my `RewriteRule`s don't work if i put the `[R=301]`.

why this don't work? `RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [R=301,L]`

It shows a `Forbidden` error when i try to access the URL `https://example.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions? it should be something 644 / 0644

Comment: @SimonHayter i have never heard about that, how can i check it?

Comment: Lookup CHMOD permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [R=301,L]
> ```

Note that `sitemap.php` is a *relative path* - it does not start with a slash (root-relative) or scheme+hostname (absolute). Relative to what?

By itself, this won't work because in a per-directory context (ie. `.htaccess`), Apache prepends *relative path substitutions* (ie. `sitemap.php`) with the directory-prefix (ie. the absolute filesystem path that leads to the `.htaccess` file. If the `.htaccess` file is in the document root, then it prepends the *document root*.)

In other words, it will result in a malformed *external redirect* to a URL of the form:

```
https://example.com/home/user/public_html/sitemap.php
```

Instead of the likely intended URL `https://example.com/sitemap.php`. (Although, whatever URL is being redirected to should be clearly visible in the browser's address bar.)

`/home/user/public_html` is whatever your directory-prefix is. This will likely result in a 404 or a 403 (as in your case), depending on your file structure and server config.

Now, before you added the `R=301` flag, this was an *internal rewrite* - and it would have been correct to prepend the directory-prefix in this instance since an *internal rewrite* is *internal* to your server.

---

To redirect to the intended URL (ie. `https://example.com/sitemap.php`), you need to either prefix the *substitution* string with a slash, to make the URL-path root-relative (or include the scheme+hostname to form an *absolute URL*). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap.php [R=301,L]
```

OR,

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ https://example.com/sitemap.php [R=301,L]
```

OR, set the `RewriteBase` directive appropriately:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive overrides the directory-prefix for relative path substitutions.

> Some of my `RewriteRule`s don't work if i put the `[R=301]`.

Yes, that is quite probable. Most `RewriteRule` directives are not intended to be *external redirects*. mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond`, etc.) is Apache's URL-rewriting module; it also does redirects.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [R=301,L]
> ```

Going back to your original directive - this probably should not be a "redirect". You should simply remove the `R=301` flag.

You will need to clear your browser cache since 301 (permanent) redirects are cached (by default) by the browser (including the ones in error).